# Traversing .prev() and .val()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a web page with a div ID="colorRecord" with a button in it. This button when clicked uses jQuery ajax to add a new div inside the colorRecord div. This can be done many times.

```
<form class="admin">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Colours</legend>
            <div id="colorRecord"><div class="color-row"><label>Color:</label><input value="" name="color" class="std-text" type="text"><input name="recordColor" value="Save" onclick="recordNewColor();return false;" type="submit"></div></div>
    <input onclick="createNewColorRow(3);return false;" value="New Color" type="button">
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Each new div has an input and an input button immediately after it. When the input button is clicked a function is called to grab the value of the input field to the left of the button. I thought:

$(this).prev().val() would have achieved my result but I am getting only undefined:

```
function recordNewColor() {
  console.log('Record Color');
  var thiscolor =  $(this).prev().val();
  console.log(thiscolor)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated:

Comment: What does `this` refer to in that function? How are you calling it? What is the structure of the DOM? *edit*: Inside `recordNewColor`, `this` does not refer to the clicked element, but to `window`. If you are using jQuery anyway, why are you using inline event handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be binding using the onclick property in the HTML.  Use jQuery instead, and using [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) will allow you to automatically bind to the new elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#colorRecord').delegate('input[name=recordColor]', 'click', function () {
    console.log('Record Color');
    var thiscolor =  $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(thiscolor)
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would you have multiple inputs with the same name ?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder...I didn't that is OPs decision.  But in anycase they are buttons and text inputs used for a specific action.  I do not believe OP is actually submitting all the form elements at once but instead using the form elements for AJAX and modifying the DOM on the fly.

Comment: This answer was perfect. Thanks. Have implemented the code and is now hooking up and working exactly as required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in `this` when you call `recordNewColor` like so:

```
<input name="recordColor" value="Save" onclick="recordNewColor(this);" type="submit">
```

And then in your `recordNewColor` function get the element as an argument:

```
function recordNewColor(el) {
  console.log('Record Color');
  var thiscolor =  $(el).prev().val();
  console.log(thiscolor);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This will function but if OP is using jQuery it would be best if he was binding events using jQuery.

Comment: Yep, I agree - was just trying to work with OPs existing code.

Comment: @JohnHartsock I'm inclined to disagree that using jQuery would be "best". I see where you're coming from, but if this works and it's simple and efficient, why bother doing it with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a context in your inline javascript. It's better not to do this inline anyways. This is a cleaner approach.

```
$('input[name="recordColor"]').click(function(){
   console.log('Record Color');
   var thiscolor =  $(this).prev().val();
   console.log(thiscolor)
});
```

Comment: This will not bind to the future added elements

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the click event through jQuery rather than putting is directly on the DOM object.

```
<form class="admin">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Colours</legend>
        <div id="colorRecord"><div class="color-row"><label>Color:</label><input value="" name="color" class="std-text" type="text"><input name="recordColor" value="Save" class="recordNewColorBtn" type="submit"></div></div>
    <input value="New Color" type="button" class="recordNewColorBtn">
   </fieldset>

</form>
```

So in the above code, I've removed the onclick attribute and gave your button an id. In the below code, you use that id to find the button object and attach the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.recordNewColorBtn', $('#colorRecord')).live('click', function() {
      console.log('Record Color');
      var thiscolor =  $(this).prev().val();
      console.log(thiscolor)
    });
});
```

.live will allow the click event to bound to any element that has the class .recordNewColorBtn regardless of when it was created.

Comment: Will not bind to future added elements

Comment: There, I modified it to automatically bind to new elements that have the .recordNewColorBtn class.

Comment: delegate would be a better method than live as he knows that each element will be added in `<div id="colorRecord">`  therefore why use live waiting for the event to bubble all the way up the DOM tree.

Comment: Adding a context to the selector does not equate the the functionality of delegate()